# Scope Resolution to a Static Function or a Pointer in Template Class

Tags: c++, templates, scope-resolution

I'm currently working on some code that someone else has written and I'm unsure of the efficiency of their method. They have a template class that uses scope resolution to access the class's members instead of having a pointer to the templatised class and accessing it that way. For example:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
    void func() {
        T::DoSomething();
    }
};

class B {
    static void DoSomething() {
        // code...
    }
};
```

I personally feel it makes the template class hard to understand, but my main area of query is the performance. Which is more efficient; using a scope resolution, or having a private member variable `A::T* p_blah` and calling `B`'s function using `p_blah->DoSomething()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scope resolution is something that happens entirely at compile time. The method used in that code results in a direct, inlinable, function call. You can't really beat that.

Your proposal:

- Requires an instance of B to be created somehow
- Requires that a pointer to that instance either be stored in `A` (increasing its size) or in a global (always problematic)
- Introduces the need to track that instance's lifetime

In short it has little chance of being as efficient as what you currently have.

Comment: I thought as much. So are there no down sides to using the static functions method? (Assuming the class has no member variables)

Comment: If by "using the static functions method" you mean the call `B::foo()` then no. Your argument that it makes the class "harder to understand" doesn't really make sense. Putting a `ptr->foo()` instead when it is intended to be a static call would "obfuscate" the template.